# Hiding Characters in Excel, I get the error: Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class

Tags: vba, excel

I just want my `cells` to have only the last 100 characters showing.

Here is my Code:

```
Sub HideCharacters()
    Dim DQ As String, mesage As String
    On Error GoTo Errorcatch
    DQ = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        mesage = Right(r.Value, 100)
        mesage = DQ & mesage & DQ
        r.NumberFormat = ";;;" & mesage
    Next r
Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

The code works for a while then as I add more worksheets and apply the macro to them, I start to get the error: "`Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class`", how can I fix this?

Thank you in advance,
-Matt

Answer (score 1):

From:

https://support.office.com/en-my/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

> Number formats in a workbook
>
> Between 200 and 250, depending on the language version of Excel that
>   you have installed

In my Excel 2010 this fails on the 207th format:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:A1000")
        c.NumberFormat = ";;;""" & c.Address(False, False) & """"
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Well that explains why it fails, thanks. Can you help me with a way to work around that?

Comment: I can't think of any way to do it other than with a hidden column and a formula to show the last 100 characters, or storing the text in a cell comment and using VBA to populate it back to the cell on selection.